# Call mysql stored procedures parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, parameter-passing, call

I develop store procedure for my counting purpose in MySQL database. When I run this, it counts all the rows that inside the table. I want  to count only today entries. And call my procedure from C# with `submittaimestamp` value equal to my form datetime picker value. What modification should I do? When I run this it giving me error:

> incorrect number of arguments for procedure wartif.allcounter; expected 0, got 1

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `allcounter`()
BEGIN
SELECT username, COUNT(IF(status='hold',1,null)) 'hold',
       COUNT(IF(status='complete',1,null)) 'complete',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='tls',1,null)) 'tls',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='rtf',1,null)) 'rtf',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='ktl',1,null)) 'ktl',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='con',1,null)) 'con',
       COUNT(IF(status='hold',1,null)) 'hold',
       COUNT(IF(status='complete',1,null)) 'complete',
       COUNT(IF(status='route',1,null)) 'route',
       COUNT(IF(status='route(*)',1,null)) 'route(*)',
       COUNT(IF(neworsecond='new',1,null)) 'new', 
       COUNT(IF(neworsecond='Second',1,null)) 'Second'
FROM loans
WHERE DATE(submittimestamp) = submitdate
group by username;

   END
```

this is how i tried t call it from my application

```
MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = new MySqlCommand("call allcounter('submitdate')", conwaqDatabase);

DateTime dateTimeValue = tdtp.Value;
cmdwaqDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("submitdate", dateTimeValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify any parameters for your sproc, so

```
WHERE DATE(submittimestamp) = submitdate
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

is undefined within the function (unless you actually have a field named `submitdate`).

The definition should be more like

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `allcounter`(IN submitdate DATE)
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since you didn't define any paramters, you're getting an exactly correct error message - the function is defined with ZERO parameters, and you're trying to pass in ONE.

Comment: and one thing could you please tell me correct way that call this procedure from C# ?

Comment: no idea. I don't deal with c#. but a sproc is just a query like any other, with somewhat different syntax. the c# scaffolding should be (hopefully) be the same.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i solve this problem ? :)